# Save text in JSON format from Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to **scrape** data from a webpage and save the **scraped** text in JSON format.
I have reached until the step where i can gather text which i want but then i cant save it in expected format. Csv or txt format is also sufficient if possible

Please help me how to save **scraped** text in JSON. Here is my code which i have extracted

```
        for k in range(0, len(op3)):
            selectweek.select_by_index(k)
            table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='list-table']")
            for row in table.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="dvFixtureInner"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/a'):
                row.click()
                mainpage = driver.window_handles[0]
                print(mainpage)
                popup = driver.window_handles[1]
                driver.switch_to.window(popup)
                time.sleep(3)

                #Meta details of match
                team1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="match-details"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a')     #Data to save
                team2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="match-details"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/a')     #Data to save
                ht = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dvHTScoreText"]')     #Data to save
                ft = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dvScoreText"]')       #Data to save
```

Answer (score 1):

Create dictionary and convert it into JSON format using `json` module.

```
import json

dictionary = {"team1" : team1, "team2": team2, "ht": ht, "ft": ft}

json_dump = json.dumps(dictionary)

with open("YourFilePath", "w") as f:
    f.write(json_dump)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary and add key-value to it. I don't know the structure of the json but this can give an idea:

```
json_data = dict()
ht = 1
ft = 2

json_data["team1"] = {"ht": ht, "ft": ft}

print(json_data)
>>> {'team1': {'ht': 1, 'ft': 2}}
```